# Responding to an idempotent HTTP POST request

Tags: http, rest, http-post

Part of our RESTful API will allow users to register an item with a serial number. As the serial number is not globally unique it cannot be used as the identifier of the resource, so we'll use a POST to the parent resource which will generate an identifier, e.g.

```
POST /my/items

<item serial-number="ABCDEF" />
```

In the case where the item is not already registered, the HTTP semantics are well defined. We return a Location header, and the registered item as the entity body, e.g.

```
HTTP 201 Created
Location: /my/items/1234    

<item id="1234" serial-number="ABCDEF" />
```

However, in the case where the item is already registered, the API should be idempotent and return the previously registered item without creating a new one. My best guess is that it should then return a 200 OK status code, and use the Content-Location header to indicate where the item actually came from, e.g.

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Location: /my/items/1234    

<item id="1234" serial-number="ABCDEF" />
```

Would this seem reasonable? I'm not entirely clear whether the Location or Content-Location is more suitable in the second case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had similar requirement recently. For idempotent operations PUT is the best way. You're right there is a mismatch between the external-id and the internal one. I solved it by creating a dedicated resource for the external id target:

```
PUT /api-user/{username}/items/{serialNumber}
```

Internally I resolve it as a CREATE in case I have no item for 'username' and 'ABCDEF' serial number or UPDATE in case I do.

In case it was a CREATE I return 201 for an UPDATE 200. Further more the returned payload contains both homegrown id and the external serial number like you suggested in your payload.

Comment: Hmmm yes actually I like this one. Although the serial numbers may not be globally unique, there is an almost 100% probability that they would be unique within the scope of a user so it could act as a scoped unique identifier. It would also solve my problem of how a device can check whether it is already registered by using a GET on this URL and checking whether the response is a 200 or 404. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.subbu.org/blog/2008/10/location-vs-content-location) is an interesting discussion on usages of the two headers.  It claims Content-Location is not defined for PUT or POST so Location is possibly the better option in your case.  It is certainly not clear cut which is better though.

Overall I think your approach makes sense though.

Comment: That article is missing a bit when it says Content-Location isn't defined for PUT and POST, the HTTP spec actually says it isn't defined for the requests but doesn't say anything about the responses. I think that it might be right though in saying that Content-Location is for alternate forms, whereas Location is the actual location. Difficult to be sure from the spec :-S